# In a hierarchical longitudinal model, is it possible to define a time-varying covariate on its own time frame, nested into the top-level time frame?

Tags: regression, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, time-varying-covariate

I've got time-varying predictor sampling events nested under each outcome sampling event (also sampled at multiple time points). So, I've got time structure at level-1 (outcomes), but also at level-2 (time-varying predictor). Level-0 is subject ID. How can I handle the time structure at both levels 1 & 2 in a hierarchical longitudinal model?

The basic longitudinal model, using the outcome `troponin` sample times `troponin_time` with the time-varying predictor `glucose`, without considering predictor time structure:

```
lme(troponin~troponin_time*glucose,random=~1|ID,data=d,na.action=na.omit)
```

Here, `glucose` is sampled at multiple times defined by `glucose_time`. How should I make use of `glucose_time` in this model?